# A way to use broadcasting using scipy.integrate?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to perform integration of function f(x, t) with respect to x and draw a plot of the resultant F(t) against t.

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

resNumb = [integrate.quad(lambda x: 0.5*(x-1)*( special.laguerre(35)(x*np.exp(-tau)) )**2*np.exp(-x), 0, np.inf)[0] for tau in list(np.linspace(0,1,50))]


r = np.sqrt(1-np.exp(-np.linspace(0,1,50)))


plt.scatter(r,resNumb)
```

I wish to make this process faster by making python to integrate this function having numpy array of tau as an argument, but scipy.integrate does not seem to support such input. I looked for numpy.vectorize, but it did not increase speed of the program. Is there any way to increase speed of this process?

Comment: Basically in numpy you only gain significant speedups by compiling the code, or making better use of existing compiled methods.  `broadcasting` only applies to operators and ufunc (and indexing).  Not to `scipy` functions that pass the task to QUADPACK (and related) functions.  Those are already compiled - except for the calls to your own function.  `np.vectorize` has a clear performance disclaimer.  It does not compile `quad` or your function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `integrate.quad_vec()` like the following.

```
tau = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
resNumb, _ = integrate.quad_vec(
    lambda x: 0.5*(x-1) * ( special.laguerre(35)(x*np.exp(-tau)) )**2 * np.exp(-x),
    0, np.inf)
```

But this algorithm sacrifices accuracy for performance, as mentioned in [the reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html).